# How are thread names populated in thread window of visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

[image]

Especially,how the thread be named by method name like `GrabberCB::BufferCB`?

Answer (score 4):

In native code (you specified C as a tag, so I'm assuming Win32), you do it by calling `SetThreadName`.

For more info, see [this informative article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx).

You can also do it in .NET by setting the `Name` property of the thread object.

> how the thread be named by method name like GrabberCB::BufferCB?

I assume the creator of the thread decided to set the name that way.

Comment: @Alan: I meant "one sets the thread name by calling `SetThreadName`". That was a general "you", not you specifically.